# What is svnserve's authz's path syntax on Windows?

Tags: svn, svnserve, authz

**Background**

I have been running **svnserve** version 1.8.17 configuration management software on my windows intranet for years with now 10 PCs. The PCs use TortoiseSVN as the client. Now I need to add another user who has access only to a sub-folder. This means altering the **authz** file.

**Problem**

When I add a path to the **authz** file, I get error *Invalid authz configuration*. Here is my sanitized **authz** file:

```
[groups]
mygroup = rtischer
othergroup = smith

[/]
@mygroup = rw

# causes 'Invalid authz configuration' when these lines are included
[Hiveware:\Hiveware\bbb\ccc\projname]
@othergroup = rw
```

And the following are my sanitized paths:

```
C:\svn\Hiveware\conf\authz
C:\svn\Hiveware\db
C:\Hiveware\bbb\ccc\projname
```

The following text, taken from [Subversion documentation page xxii](http://jtdan.com/vcs/svn/1.8/svn-book.pdf), says my path syntax is correct:

> For consistency, the examples in this book assume that the reader is
>   using a Unix-like operating system and is relatively comfortable with
>   Unix and command-line interfaces. That said, the svn program also runs
>   on nonUnix platforms such as Microsoft Windows. With a few minor
>   exceptions, such as the use of backward slashes () instead of forward
>   slashes (/) for path separators, the input to and output from this
>   tool when run on Windows are identical to that of its Unix
>   counterpart.

I couldn't find out what those "minor exceptions" were though.

**Question**

Is there another syntax that works? Or is this really a bug after all these years?

Comment: For the record,  I  never got  this to work despite @barhep's good help. His answer is still valid though in the sense that he corrected and made precise the syntax for the windows path. That leaves me with the conclusion that there is a bug in **svnserve** for the windows platform.

Comment: Note that you did not show us the contents of your `authz` file. Only some `aaa bbb ccc` examples.

Comment: I updated the **Problem** section to reflect exactly (although sanitized) my *authz* file. I show the paths on my **svnserve** PC. I am in doubt whether the root folder, *Hiveware*, should be repeated after the colon (ie, *[Hiveware:\bbb\ccc\projname]*. I tested both ways and both failed.

Comment: Please see the updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61776809/761095

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [SVNBook | Path-based authoriztion](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/pathbasedauthz/) and consider examples given in this chapter.

```
# causes 'Invalid authz configuration' when these lines are included
[C:\aaa\bbb\ccc\smith]
```

The `authz` expects paths *within the repository*. It is OS-independent and has nothing to do with paths on your filesystem. Therefore, the line should look as follows

```
[REPOSITORYNAME:/MyProject/smith]
```

IMPORTANT: Paths is Subversion are case-sensitive. Therefore, you should make sure that paths in your `authz` file are correct.

### Update

The directory at `C:\svn\Hiveware\` is your repository. `C:\Hiveware\bbb\ccc\projname` is a path of a working copy checked out from a repository - it is irrelevant to the question.

When you use `svnserve`, the path to the authz file is specified in the `svnserve.conf` as value of the `authz-db` directive. Please make sure that the path is correct. You should also make sure that you correctly specify the repositories root `-r` when starting `svnserve`. In your case is has to point to `C:\svn`.

Assuming that everything else is correct, the line in your `authz-db` file should be as follows

```
[Hiveware:/bbb/ccc/projname]
```

Note forward slashes instead of back slashes and that the name of the repository is omitted after `:`. The name is already specified in the line and you don't need repeat it again.

Comment: I only have one repository so the path should be: [/aaa/bbb/ccc/smith]. Capitalization has been checked. But when I do a *repo-browser* command, I still get **Authorization failed**. Same error whether the command is done from *aaa*, *smith* or on a file in *smith*. At least the **authz** file is no longer invalid though.

Comment: even if you have only one repository you need to specify the name of the repository as `[REPOSITORYNAME:` unless you use per-repository authz files. Check the server's logs for additional hints.

Comment: Adding the repository name makes the path become: [aaa:/aaa/bbb/ccc/smith]. This syntax works. Unfortunately, *smith* now has rw access to all files so something must still be wrong with the path. Should the path start from after the base?

Comment: @rtischer8277 remove aaaa after first slash. this is a nameof the repository, not a *path within this repository*.

Comment: The path is now [aaa:/bbb/ccc/smith]. Authorization fails up and down the tree. Where would I find the server logs you mentioned above on Windows ?

Comment: @rtischer8277 1. Please note that I cannot give any more hints without seeing the content of the `authz` file and the paths in your repository. 2. I would recommend that you carefully examine your file and compare it with the examples from SVNBook (see the link in the answer). 3. You would not have all these problems should use [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) - it provides a UI to manage repository permissions. 4. Read about Apache logging at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging

Comment: I tested changing `[\]` to `[Hiveware:/]` expecting the behavior to be the same as without the repository name. I wasn't. I got a popup asking me if I wanted to work offline as there was a problem contacting the server.

Comment: Success. Sensing there is a problem with the REPOSITORY: section, I removed it so only `[/bbb/ccc/projname]` was left and it worked. Perhaps there is a bug in the windows implementation.

Comment: Probably no bug, just a fragile implementation that was never tested for windows-one-only-repository, in this case `Hiveware`. Meaning, it was implied by the developer (or overlooked) that you wouldn't put a repository name in the section since it doesn't need one.

Comment: @rtischer8277 thank you for the info. I think that I will have to test this in a testing environment. Note that SVN 1.8.x is outdated and is not supported anymore (it does not receive any patch updates). The latest release is 1.13.x (non-LTS) and SVN 1.14.0 is going to be released soon.